# Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGIN'

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, linked-server

I'm facing a very specific issue on my SQL Server instance. Recently, I had to create a Linked Server (referencing server B) in my server A, to connect to a database in B through A. Everything worked and works well when I'm in the server A (accessing via remote desktop).

I need to query the server A through an Apache application, it always works. But when I query server B through A using Apache (not in remote desktop, where it works), the query fails, so I open SSMS and execute the same query and it returns the following error:

> Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGIN'

What really concerns me is that it's not an authentication error (even though the message says it), because when I access the server A via RD, execute the query and come back to the Apache application, then I am able to query, which makes no sense at all.

It looks like it's an intermittent issue, and sometimes I just can't force it.

Answer (score 2):

Likely your two servers are not properly setup correctly either with [SPNs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/native-client/features/service-principal-name-spn-support-in-client-connections?view=sql-server-ver16) or [Kerberos delegation](https://blog.netwrix.com/2021/11/30/what-is-kerberos-delegation-an-overview-of-kerberos-delegation/), which are usually the two root factors at play for this kind of error and the symptoms you mentioned. When a Linked Server object works when directly queried from `ServerA` to `ServerB` but returns the error "*Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGIN'*" when queried from a third machine, that's usually a sign of a [double hop](https://houseofbrick.com/blog/microsoft-made-an-easy-button-for-spn-and-double-hop-issues/#:%7E:text=Double%20hop%20issues%20are%20when,is%20made%20using%20Kerberos%20authentication.) issue as a result from one of the aforementioned root causes.

Please see [my answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/313945/150011) to the same kind of question recently posted on here, where it was a Kerberos issue. Also please see [my related question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/287180/150011) where I also exhibited a Kerberos issue myself. There's a ton of information on troubleshooting these issues, among each of the answers posted there.

---

One workaround to this issue, when one doesn't want to deal with Kerberos authentication, is to setup your Linked Server to use a dedicated SQL Login, as noted in my linked DBA.StackExchange answer:

> Alternatively, if you changed that to "Be made using this security context" and entered the credentials for a SQL Login (as opposed to a Windows Authentication Login) that has access to server `A`, then that would solve your issue too. Because now, no longer would it try to pass-through the currently authenticated user's security context, rather it would use the one of the specified SQL Login. This makes it no longer a double hop, from a security perspective.
>
> The downside to that solution is that you have to ensure the SQL Login you choose has the appropriate access on server `A` that supports all your use cases of the Linked Server. Anyone who uses that Linked Server will now be accessing server `A` as the SQL Login that you entered the credentials for in your Linked Server object. You have to be careful drawing the line between over- and under-provisioning that SQL Login's permissions on server `A`.

Answer (score 0):

This is a delegation-related issue first and foremost as it requires additional setup beyond typical Kerberos (which tends to happen automagically as SPNs are registered/deregistered at startup/shutdown) connections, but that doesn't mean you don't have issues related to Kerberos as well, but cross that bridge only if you come to it.

Be warned, there are a number of different types of delegation one can employ in their environment, so I'll [point you to my answer on another dba.se question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/245236/how-to-stop-using-sql-server-login-credentials-in-a-linked-server/249435#249435) outlining what those are, how to properly configure them, as well as some pitfalls associated with each.  While that question is related to Linked-Servers, the approach for delegation outlined in that answer will be the same as you need here.  Comment if you have any questions.